# Getting a Topshelf service to run once on boot, then stop

Tags: windows-services, topshelf

I have written a TopShelf service / console app, which appears to be running as intended, except I would like it to run once on boot, then disable itself until the next boot/reboot.

I was hoping this would work:

```
class MyServiceClass
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // do the things that need doing

        this.Stop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
    }
```

But that doesn't work, presumably because the this.Stop() command is there for cleanup, not for causing the service to stop.

My Program.cs looks like this:

```
// Uses Topshelf: http://topshelf-project.com/
// Guided by: http://www.ordina.nl/nl-nl/blogs/2013/maart/building-windows-services-with-c-and-topshelf/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Topshelf;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
            {
                hostConfigurator.Service<MyServiceClass>(serviceConfigurator =>
                {
                    serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyServiceClass());
                    serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(myServiceClass => myServiceClass.Start());
                    serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(myServiceClass => myServiceClass.Stop());
                });

                hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

                hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("MyService");
                hostConfigurator.SetDescription("Does stuff.");
                hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
                hostConfigurator.StartAutomatically();
                hostConfigurator.EnableShutdown();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

How do I go about stopping the service at the end of execution?

UPDATE: Based on Damien's input, I now have:

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    private readonly Task task;
    private HostControl hostControl;

    public MyServiceClass()
    {
        task = new Task(DoWork);
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listen very carefully, I shall say this only once");
        hostControl.Stop();
    }

    public void Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        // so we can stop the service at the end of the check
        this.hostControl = hostControl;

        // start the DoWork thread
        task.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

};
```

and an updated Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Service<MyServiceClass>((serviceConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyServiceClass());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted((myServiceClass, hostControl) => myServiceClass.Start(hostControl));
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(myServiceClass => myServiceClass.Stop());
            });    /* compiler thinks there's a ")" missing from this line */

            hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

            hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.SetDescription("Does stuff.");
            hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.StartAutomatically();
            hostConfigurator.EnableShutdown();
        });

    }
};
```

However, this will not compile. My compiler suggests that a ")" is missing on (or around) my comment (shown in the code above), but any addition of a close parenthesis just adds to the error list.

I feel like I'm close... any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check the [documentation](http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html): "Each of the `WhenXxx` methods can also take an argument of the `HostControl` interface ... The `HostControl` interface can be retained and used as the service is running to Stop the service." (Although you probably need to move your `//do the things that need doing` and using the `HostControl` interface out into a separate thread because I think you have to have *returned* from your `Start` method before you attempt to stop the service)

Comment: Thanks Damien.  I'll post my code once it's working.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I am updating the question to reflect my attempt to implement use of HostControl, and would appreciate your (and everyone else's) input.

Comment: Additionally, pre-compile, intellisense says "Error: Delegate 'System.Func<MyNamespace.MyServiceClass>' does not take one argument.

Comment: note i think you are missing a ')' - you have one to many opening bracket in in the line reading `` ((serviceConfigurator =>``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got this working eventually:

```
public class MyServiceClass : ServiceControl
{
    private readonly Task task;
    private HostControl hostControl;

    public MyServiceClass()
    {
        task = new Task(DoWork);
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listen very carefully, I shall say this only once");
        //hostControl.Stop();
    }

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        // so we can stop the service at the end of the check
        this.hostControl = hostControl;

        // start the DoWork thread
        task.Start();

        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        return true;
    }

};
```

and

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Service<MyServiceClass>(serviceConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyServiceClass());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted((myServiceClass, hostControl) => myServiceClass.Start(hostControl));
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped((myServiceClass, hostControl) => myServiceClass.Stop(hostControl));
            });

            hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

            hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.SetDescription("Does stuff.");
            hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.StartAutomatically();
            hostConfigurator.EnableShutdown();
        });

    }
};
```

My 2nd attempt had a spare "(" at the first mention of serviceConfigurator, then I needed to turn my void Start and Stop functions into bool functions.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For this to work, you need to uncomment hostControl.Stop();